# how to fix :SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

how i can fix this error ?

this is my error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`coachers`.`article_comments`, CONSTRAINT
>   `article_comments_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES
>   `users` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `article_comments` (`name`, `email`,
>   `description`, `article_id`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
>   values (aaaaa, aaa@gmail.com, hhhhhhsssshhshsh, 1, 0, 2019-10-17
>   08:12:17, 2019-10-17 08:12:17))

```
 public function commentArticle($user_id, $article_id, Request $request)
    {

        if (!$user_id == 0) {
            $register = $request->validate([
                'description' => 'required|min:5',
            ]);
            $commentarticle = new articleComment();
            $commentarticle->description = $request->input('description');
            $commentarticle->user_id = $user_id;
            $commentarticle->article_id = $article_id;
            $commentarticle->name = 'name';
            $commentarticle->email = 'email';
            $commentarticle->submit = 0;
            $commentarticle->save();
            return $request;

        }
        else if ($user_id == 0) {
            $register = $request->validate([
                'description' => 'required|min:5',
                'name' => 'required|min:3',
                'email' => 'required|min:5|max:150|email',
            ]);
            $comment = new articleComment();
            $comment->name = $request->input('name');
            $comment->email = $request->input('email');
            $comment->description = $request->input('description');
            $comment->article_id = $article_id;
            $comment->user_id = 0;
            $comment->save();
            return $comment;
        }
    }
```

and my api :

```
Route::post('comment-article/{user_id}/{article_id}', 'ArticleController@commentArticle');
```

and my table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('article_comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->unique()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->unsignedInteger('article_id')->unique()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles');
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->nullable();
            $table->string('submit')->nullable();
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `unique()` method from `user_id` and `article_id` column  and rerun migration again..

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('article_comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->unsignedInteger('article_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles');
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->nullable();
            $table->string('submit')->nullable();
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

if `user_id` is not there then **user_id** set a **null** **not a (zero)0**

```
$comment->user_id = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no user with `id` == 0 in your `users` table. And since there is a foreign key constraint the operation fails.